# YouTube iFrame embed pausing after few seconds

Tags: macos, cocoa, flash, webview, youtube

I have a Mac OS X application and am using a WebView (webkit) to embed a YouTube iframe.

For some reason it keeps pausing on certain videos after a few seconds. It will just get stuck loading.

Flash NPAPI Plug-in version 18.0.0.160 is installed.

Xcode is also throwing an Error: `Ignoring controlTimebase set by client because AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer was added to a synchronizer`

Here is my code for the iFrame embed, the same one as YouTube provides.

```
<div id="ytplayer"></div>
<script>
  document.body.setAttribute("style", "margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px;background-color:#000000");
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
  var player;

  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '200',
      width: '300',
      videoId: '%@',
      playerVars: {
        'controls': 0,
        'html5': 1,
        'autoplay': 1
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

It was working fine until a couple days ago. I believe YouTube might have updated something, which could just mean the error is on their end.

Comment: YouTube started to play videos using the HTML5 player by default instead of flash player, right click on the video and at the bottom of the context menu you can see the "About" menu item, the item text will immediately show you which player type is in use currently, I guess you will see now the "About the HTML5 Player" text, that means you have problem with the HTML5 player buffering (just like for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31306131/embedding-a-youtube-video-using-youtube-player-api-in-a-cocoa-webkit-control-tha)

Comment: the one and only still (who knows how long?) working flash player based solution I found is "http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?version=3" any iframe embedding formula now defaults to use the HTML5 version